# Wygwym replace file: The file could not be written to disk

Tags: wygwam, uploads

I'm using wygwam 3.2.2 and EE 2.7.2. I'm attempting to overwrite a file from the upload diaglog "The file could not be written to disk." However, this is only on certain user groups. The super-admin group allows you to and brings up the "rename file". Am I missing a setting somewhere? I checked that that user group is allowed to upload files in that directory (and they can). However, this issue only occurs when a user in a particular group attempts to overwrite a file. Any thoughts?

Comment: "unique to certain user groups" meaning some groups besides super-admin work but some don't?

Comment: Is this a PDF you're trying to upload? Sometimes EE's XSS filtering blocks file uploads if the file fails the security test - this often affects PDF's generated with MS Word and InDesign...

Comment: @Bluedreamer - This might be a silly question, but wouldn't turning off XSS filtering be a bit of a security risk? I'm nervous to do this in any implementation :/